# Date is supposed to be validating to true but it is not

Tags: ruby

I have:

```
params[:manually_paid_at] # => 02/02/2019
```

An action in one of my helper methods is like this:

```
Date.strptime(params[:manually_paid_at], "%m-%d-%Y") rescue nil
```

As far as I know, this is a valid date. I checked it by running a test console session as follows:

```
mydate = "02/02/2019"
Date.strptime(mydate, "%m-%d-%Y") # >> ArgumentError: invalid date
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `%m-%d-%Y` is using `-`. `02/02/2019` is using `/`.

Comment: It took me a couple of minutes to decipher what you're saying. So, strptime is expecting a dash (-) rather than a slash (/), Is there a Ruby or Rails method to verify if a date is valid, without having to convert slashes to dashes?

Comment: `Date.parse(.....)` will try to make sense of the input. But it's not a *validator*, per say. In order to *validate* a date/time input, it needs to have a well-defined format.

Comment: https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-parse -- *"This method does not function as a validator"*.

Comment: For strings like `02/02/2019`, try using `Date.strptime(mydate, "%m/%d/%Y")`

Comment: I misunderstood how strptime worked. @khelwood suggestion worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your date string does not match your format string.

For strings like `"02/02/2019"`, try using:

```
Date.strptime(mydate, "%m/%d/%Y")
```